# WCF REST problems while deserializing XElement

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer, wcf-rest

I have a WCF REST service that acts on a POST, receiving a XML and returning another one.
As of now, other methods that get a XML are working fine.

It seems that DataContractSerializer is unable to deserialize a XML text into a XElement, although I managed to do it using DataContractSerializer directly on a PoC:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stream = File.Open("afile.xml", FileMode.Open); // afile.xml has the same contect as the request below
    var serial = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(XElement));
    var obj = serial.ReadObject(stream); //obj is a XElement instance
}
```

The problem when I try to POST a XML to my REST service is this exception:

```
<Exception>
  <ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
  <Message>Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'documento' and root namespace 'http://uri.org' (for operation 'Publicar' and contract ('IDocumentos',  'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.</Message>
  <StackTrace>
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
    at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
    at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
    at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
    at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
    at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
    at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
    at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
    at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  </StackTrace>
  <ExceptionString>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'documento' and root namespace 'http://uri.org' (for operation 'Publicar' and contract ('IDocumentos',  'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
```

The contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDocumentos
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    XElement Publicar(XElement documento);
}
```

And the request being sent through Fiddler:

```
POST http://integracao/documentos/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: integracao
Content-Length: 46
Content-Type: text/xml

<documento></documento>
```

The routes are added at Application_Start, creating a ServiceHostFactory and using it to add routes to the RouteTable.

I've checked around for other questions but none seemed to be affected like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind it, I found out that the service I was trying to execute was published with an old version which hadn't XElement on the parameters, instead, it was a class, so it wouldn't work anyway.

I'm sorry for the waste of time it might have caused!

Comment: please post this comment as an answer and accept it, to make it easier for people to skip over this question.

Comment: Yep, I tried but at that time I couldn't, SO told me wait for 6h. They've passed now, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind it, I found out that the service I was trying to execute was published with an old version which hadn't XElement on the parameters, instead, it was a class, so it wouldn't work anyway.

I'm sorry for the waste of time it might have caused!